# Как добавить дату в таблицу sql из inline keyboard в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, sqlite

Вынужден обратиться за помощью!
Я нахожусь на этапе изучения Python и решил для практики сделать свой мини - проект.

Пишу ТГ бота для записи на сервис, хоть код получается костыльный, но мне важен результат.

Вообщем надыбал в сети календарь, подстроил под себя и столкнулся с проблемой.

Фрагмент кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])
def start(m):
    calendar, step = WMonthTelegramCalendar(locale='ru', min_date=date.today()).build()
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id,
                     f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                     reply_markup=calendar)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=WMonthTelegramCalendar.func())
def cal(c):
    result, key, step = WMonthTelegramCalendar(locale='ru', min_date=date.today()).process(c.data)
    if not result and key:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                              c.message.chat.id,
                              c.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=key)
    elif result:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"You selected {result}",
                              c.message.chat.id,
                              c.message.message_id)
```

Сам календарь брал здесь: https://github.com/artembakhanov/python-telegram-bot-calendar

**Суть проблемы**, как закинуть выбранную дату в таблицу sqlite?

Пытался сделать по аналогии с регистрацией пользователя, но т.к пользователь в чат ничего не пишет, message он и не обрабатывает:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=WMonthTelegramCalendar.func())
def cal(c):
    result, key, step = WMonthTelegramCalendar(locale='ru', min_date=date.today()).process(c.data)
    if not result and key:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                              c.message.chat.id,
                              c.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=key)
    elif result:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"You selected {result}",
                              c.message.chat.id,
                              c.message.message_id)

        bot.register_next_step_handler(process_date_step)


def process_date_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.date = message.result

        sql = "INSERT INTO date (user_date) VALUES (?)"
        val = (user.date)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Дату записал')
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'чот не записывается дата')
```

Выдает ошибку: **TypeError: register_next_step_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'**

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это обыграть, чтобы оно заработало?

Прошу, не судите за столь глупые вопросы, все мы когда-то только начинали :)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нет многих необходимых проверок, но надеюсь, сам принцип добавления значений в базу данных станет ясен.

```
# python-telegram-bot-calendar==1.0.5
from telegram_bot_calendar import DetailedTelegramCalendar, LSTEP
import sqlite3
from typing import Union

def date(message: types.Message) -> None:
    """Функция для формирующая инлайн-календарь"""
    calendar, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().build()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Select {LSTEP[step]}", reply_markup=calendar)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=DetailedTelegramCalendar.func())
def cal(c: types.CallbackQuery) -> None:
    """Функция для выбора даты через инлайн-календарь"""
    result, key, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().process(c.data)
    if not result and key:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                              c.message.chat.id,
                              c.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=key)
    elif result:
        bot.delete_message(int(c.message.chat.id), c.message.message_id)
        adding_values_db(c.message.chat.id, result, param='date')


def processing_user_db(people_id: int) -> None:
    """
    Функция, создающая таблицы базы данных SQLite   
    :param people_id
    :return: None
    """

    connect = sqlite3.connect('db\\users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
        user_id INTEGER,
        date TEXT);
    """)
    connect.commit()


def adding_user_id_db(id: int) -> None:
    """Функция добавляет id нового пользователя в таблицу users"""
    connect = sqlite3.connect('db\\users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = {id}")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        user_id = [id]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id) VALUES(?);", user_id)
        connect.commit()

def adding_values_db(people_id: int, value: Union[int, float, str, None], param: str) -> None:
    """Функция добавляет значение по id пользователя в таблицу users в столбец со значением param"""
    connect = sqlite3.connect('db\\users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = {people_id}")
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET {param} = \"{value}\" WHERE user_id = {people_id}")
    connect.commit()
```

Comment: Если не охота разбираться, то обрати еще внимание не передачу result в свою функцию process_date_step. Я его передаю без метода register_next_step_handler в виде аргумента в функции adding_values_db(c.message.chat.id, result, param='date')

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что заморочились и дали внятный ответ